# apache deflate module not working

Tags: apache-2.2, gzip, mod-deflate, deflate

it's very strage, i google a problem with no luck at all.
i have 2 servers (centos6, apache2.2). apache configuration is totally the same (i sure, apache configured by puppet)

my deflate.conf:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript application/javascript application/ecmascript text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
```

when i *curl -I --compressed http://web1.tld/file.css* i get following responce:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 19 Sep 2014 15:02:21 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Fri, 19 Sep 2014 08:36:46 GMT
ETag: "189dc-50367005ed32a"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=2419200
Expires: Fri, 17 Oct 2014 15:02:21 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 16191
Content-Type: text/css
```

It is ok, i see *Content-Encoding: gzip*

with second server: *curl -I --compressed http://web2.tld/file.css*

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 19 Sep 2014 15:03:47 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Fri, 19 Sep 2014 08:36:46 GMT
ETag: "189dc-50367005ed32a"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 100828
Cache-Control: max-age=2419200
Expires: Fri, 17 Oct 2014 15:03:47 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/css
```

and it is NOT ok: *Content-Length: 100828* and **no** header *Content-Encoding: gzip*

BUT! strange is here: When i do the same request from web1 to web2 server - gzip is enabled on web2!

also please advise if it possible to send 'Vary' header ONLY when request have 'Accept-Encoding' ?